# nextInt() having issues in a while loop

Tags: java, while-loop, iterator, java.util.scanner

Basically I need this while loop to perform 4 times

It will ask user for input then use that input in the nested if statements. (repeat 4 times)

The first prompt will show up and I am able to type an input.

but after that it just gives me an error.

and keeps pointing the error to "int userInput = scan.nextInt();"

I have no idea whats wrong with it. Can someone guide me? thanks

```
    int count = 0;

    while (count < 4 ) {

        System.out.println(prompt1);
        int userInput = scan.nextInt();

        (some nested if statements here to do my task, they all have
         count++ at the end)

    }
```

Comment: **What** error are you getting? Where you define and initialize `scan`?

Comment: initialized it outside the while loop

Comment: Can we see that code? Also post the entire error/exception that you are getting.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Always check if the nextInt is available before asking for it :

```
if(scan.hasNextInt())
{
 int userInput = scan.nextInt();
 // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to define scan

`Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);`